# High-frequency scheduling with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, scheduling, apscheduler

I've used APScheduler in the past to schedule function calls every X seconds with great success. However, I'm looking to call a function multiple times per second, which neither the IntervalTrigger or CronTrigger APScheduler functions seem to allow.

Is there a simple way to set the interval to a fraction of second, or will I need to look at threading options?

Answer (score 1):

With APScheduler, providing sub-second accuracy is not very feasible. Do you really need the extra features provided by the library? If not, you could just have a loop where you use time.sleep().

Comment: You're right, after some further thought I don't think this is the best way to proceed. I'm currently playing with the threading.Timer() function, which appears to offer the functionality I'm after.